# Combining JavaFX 3D Shapes seem transparent

Tags: java, 3d, javafx-8, javafx-3d

I'm working on a 3D project in JavaFX 8. I have built a Car 3d Model with several TriangleMesh objects I'm also using several other JavaFX 'Shape 3D's to create the wheels and axles.

The problem is that the MeshViews elements seem transparent. I can see the other Shape3D objects thru it

[image] 
*2 Cylinders are visible even though the MeshView is in front of it*

Here is an example of one of the TriangleMesh's I made

```
// =============================  ROOF ============================= // 

    TriangleMesh roofMesh = new TriangleMesh(VertexFormat.POINT_TEXCOORD);

    roofMesh.getPoints().addAll(
            /* X */ -roofWidth/2.f,  /* Y */    roofHeight + wheelDiameter / 2  + wheelGap + doorHeight, /* Z */ - roofLength/2,    //PT0
            /* X */ roofWidth/2.f,   /* Y */    roofHeight + wheelDiameter / 2  + wheelGap + doorHeight, /* Z */ - roofLength/2,    //PT1
            /* X */ -roofWidth/2.f,  /* Y */    roofHeight + wheelDiameter / 2  + wheelGap + doorHeight, /* Z */  roofLength/2,     //PT2
            /* X */ roofWidth/2.f,   /* Y */    roofHeight + wheelDiameter / 2  + wheelGap + doorHeight, /* Z */  roofLength/2      //PT3
            );

    roofMesh.getTexCoords().addAll(
            0, 0,  //  t0
            1, 0,  //  t1
            0, 1,  //  t2
            1, 1   //  t3
            );

    roofMesh.getFaces().addAll(
            1,1, 0,0,2,2,
            3,3, 1,2 ,2,1
            );
```

After Creating the mesh I'm creating a new MeshView object

```
        meshViewMap.put("roof",          new MeshView(roofMesh));
```

I have also applied a Material to the MeshViews:

```
private void setTexColor(Shape3D shape, Color c, String imagePath )
{
    PhongMaterial pm = new PhongMaterial();
    pm.setDiffuseColor(c);
    pm.setSpecularColor(c);
    shape.setMaterial(pm);
}
```

These are the Cylinder that you can see in the image:

```
    //Create Axles
            Cylinder frontCylinder = new Cylinder(0.5, bodyWidth);
            Cylinder rearCylinder = new Cylinder(0.5, bodyWidth);
            PhongMaterial cylinderMat = new PhongMaterial();
            cylinderMat.setDiffuseColor(Color.BLACK);
            cylinderMat.setSpecularColor(Color.BLACK);

            frontCylinder.setMaterial(cylinderMat);
            rearCylinder.setMaterial(cylinderMat);

            frontCylinder.setRotate(90);
            rearCylinder.setRotate(90);
            frontCylinder.setTranslateZ( 0.7f * (bodyLength/2 + hoodLength/2));
            rearCylinder.setTranslateZ( -0.4f * (bodyLength/2 + hoodLength/2));

            frontCylinder.setTranslateY(wheelDiameter/2);
            rearCylinder.setTranslateY(wheelDiameter/2);
            this.getChildren().add(frontCylinder);
            this.getChildren().add(rearCylinder);
```

I have tried to set the opacity to 1 even though it is the default value.

Java Version 8.0.121-b13

Comment: Did you enable the depth buffer (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#Scene-javafx.scene.Parent-double-double-boolean-) ?

Comment: THANK YOU @fabian! you saved me many hours of frustration !
Just needed to add the flag in the Scene constructor!
I tried to find a way to change this property after creating the object and it seems that there is no other way to change this feature but the constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, a JavaFX [Scene](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html) doesn't include a [depth buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering). When used for 3D, this may result in weird Escherian artifacts where objects or surfaces farther from the camera are drawn on top of those closer to the camera.

> An application may request depth buffer support or scene anti-aliasing support at the creation of a Scene. A scene with only 2D shapes and without any 3D transforms does not need a depth buffer nor scene anti-aliasing support.

To enable the depth buffer, use [one of the constructors that takes a `boolean depthBuffer` argument](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#%3Cinit%3E(javafx.scene.Parent,double,double,boolean)).

For a [SubScene](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/SubScene.html), the [corresponding constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/SubScene.html#%3Cinit%3E(javafx.scene.Parent,double,double,boolean,javafx.scene.SceneAntialiasing)) also requires a [`SceneAntialiasing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/SceneAntialiasing.html) argument. (The default value would be `SceneAntialiasing.DISABLED`.)

(Based on [Fabian's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43144497/combining-javafx-3d-shapes-seem-transparent#comment73366368_43144497), for those who don't look closely at comments.)